# Filtering data frame by conditionality in pandas

Tags: pandas, filter, count

I have a dataframe where all columns are having the data type of object. I am running a python syntax to filter rows by conditions.

Here is the syntax:

```
condition1=dataframe[dataframe['Earnings']=='<=50K']
condition2= dataframe[dataframe["Degree Status"]=="HS-grad"]
condition3=dataframe[dataframe["Country"]=="United-States"]


df= condition1 & condition2 & condition3
```

I am expecting to get output filtered by the different conditions and joined by &. "<=50K" is string.  However, the output is empty. I can't figure out where my mistake is. Anyone with better suggestion?

Comment: Why are you using `.count()`?

Comment: edited! But still the output is empty []

Comment: What you want is `df= dataframe[(dataframe['Earnings']=='<=50K') & (dataframe["Degree Status"]=="HS-grad") & (dataframe["Country"]=="United-States")]`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are looking for a way to filter for rows that have specific values in specific columns.

You can do that as follows

```py
df = dataframe[(dataframe['Earnings'] == '<=50k') 
   & (dataframe["Degree Status"]=="HS-grad") 
   & (dataframe["Country"]=="United-States")]
```

In your attempt, each condition was returning a *dataframe*. What you could have done in your approach, however, is to return a boolean mask instead. Your code would then looking something like

```py
condition1= dataframe['Earnings']=='<=50K'
condition2= dataframe["Degree Status"]=="HS-grad"
condition3= dataframe["Country"]=="United-States"

df = dataframe[condition1 & condition2 & condition3]
```